# Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type (and they are the same thing)

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

This doesn't make any sense to me:

> Argument of type '(string | (new () => Middleware) | Middleware)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(string | Middleware | (new () => Middleware))[]'.

The two are the same thing right? The only difference that I see is the order of the items. However, typescript is changing the order in which I defined them, so I was assuming that the order wasn't an issue.

I think the issues is because I am using two packages that are referencing one another, and it doesn't know how to resolve the issue properly..

**@red5/server -> Middleware.ts**

```
import { Client } from '.'
import { Route } from '@red5/router'

export interface Middleware { }

public static async run(theRoute: Route, client: Client): Promise<boolean | Response> {
  let middleware = theRoute.routeOptions.middleware
  this._runPreMiddleware(middleware, client)
}

private static async _runPreMiddleware(middleware: ((new () => Middleware) | Middleware | string)[], client: Client): Promise<boolean | Response> {

}
```

**@red5/router -> Route.ts**

```
import { Middleware } from '@red5/server'

export interface RouterOptions {
  middleware?: ((new () => Middleware) | Middleware | string)[]
  name?: string
}

export class Route {
  public routeOptions: RouterOptions = {}
}
```

Here is a larger version of the error, My takeaway from this error is that it is comparing source code to a definition file to resolve the type.

```
Argument of type '(string | (new () => Middleware) | Middleware)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(string | Middleware | (new () => Middleware))[]'.
  Type 'string | (new () => Middleware) | Middleware' is not assignable to type 'string | Middleware | (new () => Middleware)'.
    Type 'new () => Middleware' is not assignable to type 'string | Middleware | (new () => Middleware)'.
      Type 'new () => import("C:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/types/Middleware").Middleware' is not assignable to type 'new () => import("c:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/src/Middleware").Middleware'.
        Type 'import("C:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/types/Middleware").Middleware' is not assignable to type 'import("c:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/src/Middleware").Middleware'.
          Types of property 'handle' are incompatible.
            Type '((client: import("C:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/types/Client").Client, ...args: any[]) => boolean | import("C:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/types/Response").Response | Promise<...>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((client: import("c:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/src/Client").Client, ...args: any[]) => boolean | import("c:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/src/Response").Response | Promise<...>) | undefined'.
              Type '(client: import("C:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/types/Client").Client, ...args: any[]) => boolean | import("C:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/types/Response").Response | Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '(client: import("c:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/src/Client").Client, ...args: any[]) => boolean | import("c:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/src/Response").Response | Promise<...>'.
                Types of parameters 'client' and 'client' are incompatible.
                  Type 'import("c:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/src/Client").Client' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/server/types/Client").Client'.
                    Types have separate declarations of a private property '_post'.ts(2345)
```

[image: Type 1]
[image: Type 2]

Comment: The actual error seems to be `Types of parameters 'client' and 'client' are incompatible.` since one version comes from `server/types/Client` and the other comes from `server/src/Client`, and these two types seem to be incompatible (`Types have separate declarations of a private property '_post'`)

Comment: @p.s.w.g I added some images that show the errors relate to param 1, but like you say the error shows that it relates to param 2...

Comment: Also what is strange, is that at compile time I get no errors.

Comment: hmm... changing `import { Client } from '.'` to `import { Client } from '@red5/server'` seems to make the errors go away.

Comment: When are you seeing the error if not at compile time?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I am seeing it in the editor

Comment: It seems like `Middleware` has a property, `handle` that is a function that accepts a `client`. I don't think the error with the `client` parameter shown in your code.

Comment: Since there is a discrepancy between the compiler and the editor, consider restarting the TypeScript language service in VS Code. (Command Pallet > "restart")

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I have done that many times, and the error keeps coming back. Unless I change the import to import the package instead of the file.

Comment: The first comment seems like the right answer - you have 2 class definitions for Client. one in `server/types` and one in `server/src`, drill down in to the classes involved  and have a look.